# Convert epoch time to readable time in excel

Tags: excel

I have a excel sheet where in column (G) there is a timestamp but is in epoch format, how can i convert epoch time to readable time format in excel.

I have already tried `=TEXT(G2,"DD/MM/YYY HH:MM:SS")` but it didn't work.

Comment: 1499423767147 - Epoch time

Comment: I want the exact result which i got from @user9211845 formula.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
=TEXT((G2/1000 + ("1/1/1970"-"1/1/1900"+1)*86400) / 86400,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS")
```

Comment: What's the point of `"1/1/1970"-"1/1/1900"+1`? Doing it that way causes the formula to fail if using 1904 date system

Comment: @barryhoudini the epoch time started from 01/01/1970 thats why i have mentioned it into the formula.

Comment: Yes, but why subtract 1/1/1900? As pnuts says you can get the answer with `="1/1/1970"+G2/86400000` to give valid time/date or use that wrapped by TEXT function to get the result as text

Comment: @barryhoudini that can also be another way but result would be the same.

Comment: No, if you are using 1904 date system you will get an error

Comment: @barryhoudini for 1904 date we would not have epoch time right??